# OpenGL Picking with Pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, picking

I'm trying to implement picking using Pyglet's OpenGL wrapper, but I'm having trouble converting a [C tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/) to Python. Specifically the part below.

```
#define BUFSIZE 512
GLuint selectBuf[BUFSIZE]

void startPicking(int cursorX, int cursorY) {
    GLint viewport[4];

    glSelectBuffer(BUFSIZE,selectBuf);
    glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewport);
    gluPickMatrix(cursorX,viewport[3]-cursorY,
            5,5,viewport);
    gluPerspective(45,ratio,0.1,1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glInitNames();
}
```

I'm not sure how to turn declare arrays of GLuint or GLint such that glSelectBuffer and glPickMatrix work. Does anyone know how to do this in Python with Pyglet? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried your particular example, but the normal way to declare arrays is in the [ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#arrays). Essentially you would create an array type like this:

```
FourGLints = GLint * 4
viewport = FourGLints(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with PyOpenGL.

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

It's pretty straightforward, and using a C tutorial would be easier with it, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what sort of trouble are you having? Pyglet's OpenGL implementation is a thin wrapper over the DLL and pretty much maps the C calls one-for-one. It's hard to imagine there would be any other library that could be better in terms of following a C tutorial.

For example, [this introduction](http://pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/using_opengl.html) is pretty much identical to the C equivalent when it comes to the OpenGL calls:

```
from pyglet.gl import *

# Direct OpenGL commands to this window.
window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glVertex2f(0, 0)
    glVertex2f(window.width, 0)
    glVertex2f(window.width, window.height)
    glEnd()

pyglet.app.run()
```